# Winjs Application on Activated event

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

I have 2 pages - an authentication page and a content page.

After authentification is successful, I save this data: `Winjs.Application.SessioState.mydata`.

At the start (on launching) of the application, I want to detect if this data is not null so I can directly move to the content page. If it *is* null, I want to render the Authentication page.

Please help me, I don't know where to put the portion of code(in default.html or default.js).

BUT in my default.html I have this line:

```
<div id="contentHost" data-win-control="MyApp.PageControlNavigator"
    data-win-options="{home: '/pages/home/home.html'}"></div>
```

(run the content page directly)

Comment: The session state will be cleared when the user shuts down the app (via Alt+F4 for example). You should consider using `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings` or `roamingSettings` instead if you want to persist this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update this block of code in default.js in 'activated' event handler.

```
args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function ()
{
    if (nav.location)
    {
        nav.history.current.initialPlaceholder = true;
        return nav.navigate(nav.location, nav.state);
    } else if (!!app.sessioState.mydata)
    {
        nav.navigate('/pages/authpage/authpage.html', optionsIfAny);
    }
    else
    {
        return nav.navigate(Application.navigator.home);
    }
}));
```